# Raised image on front page

Tags: graphics

I want to put an image on my front title page, but a little above the mergins
(so it would start on almost the very top of the A4 page). How do I manage this?

Comment: Where do you want it - at the center?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in number of ways. My favorite is `tikz` using its `remember picture` and `overlay` combination.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in,showframe]{geometry} %% showframe is to show margins. Remove that in your file
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[anchor=north] at (current page.north)  {\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

[image]